# How to get RAM size in JavaME Netbeans

Tags: netbeans, java-me, ram

I am working on JavaME client application in Netbeans. Now, I want to know the size of the RAM that alloted to the JavaME simulator. I have tried to find out the size of RAM in JavaME Netbeans simulator. But I didn't get it.
Can you please suggest me, how to get the size of the RAM in JavaME simulator.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found good article on Java ME memory requirements and its CLDC specifications at http://www.techopedia.com/definition/24254/java-platform-micro-edition-java-me
and,
http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/CLDC
These articles helped me and I hope it helps you also. Thanks.